# What determines the width of a div class when it's not defined?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, column-width

I am trying to resize the sidebar column in this [example](http://html5up.net/uploads/demos/halcyonic/twocolumn2.html).

It's currently at 25% (column .3u).  I would like to expand it to an equivalent of 26% without shrinking the actual main area (column .9u).  The only way I see to accomplish is to increase the width of the container div (class .row).  But I don't see the width of that class defined in Chrome's "Inspect Element" view!  Nor am I seeing the margins or padding of .row, which would push its contents toward the middle and indirectly set its width.

Am I looking in the wrong place, or is Chrome not the best tool to inspect the CSS for this purpose?

Comment: Did not understand your question completely but I could see the widths of `3u` and `9u` classes in chrome toolbar, F12 and then magnifier icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clearly see the width is applied to `.container` class in chrome dev tools.

```
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1200px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I see now that it's not .row, but .container that defines the width of the sum of both columns.  What threw me off is that Chrome uses the blue color to highlight .row, but it uses orange for the empty space around it when you select .container.  That made me think that .container is row + emtpy space.  Of course, the people on Stack Overflow are quick to downvote a newbie who misreads something and heaven forbid asks a question about it.

Comment: Great if this helped and for your record I did not down vote this post.